# How much time.deltatime matters in 2D movement?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
void movement()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, speed*Time.deltaTime);
}

void movement()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, speed);
}
```

Both code works perfectly fine for a simple moving in Y direction. I wanted to know whether or not in a simple 2D game where framerate isn't really a bother, does using time.deltatime really matters? Which method should I go for if there any difference at all.

Comment: It matters when people play your game on a different machine than yours. Their frame rate / cpu might be faster or slower. Using deltatime will make the movement speed the same across devices.

Comment: I understand that's what time.deltatime does. But I dont think any device will have any issue running such a simple game like this. Should I still put this extra code regardless just because its good practice?

Comment: "where framerate isn't really a bother" Don't assume that. Someone is inevitably going to try running your game on a toaster. Also, even if the framerate never goes very low, there is still the possibility of it going very **high**, at which point the game would speed up. So it's a good idea to use `Time.deltaTime`, no matter what your performance is like.

Comment: You could try running your game on a device with 120Hz screen refresh rate and see if it runs twice as fast. I've seen it happen before! Deltatime will also correct for small inconsistencies in CPU time.

Comment: Multiplying a speed constant by delta time to calculate rigidbody velocity is as inappropriate on a toaster as it is on a cray. do not do it.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying something by [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

> The interval in seconds from the last frame to the current one

converts a value from a fixed value per frame into a value per second. This is usually quite essential for continous frame-rate independent movements. And yes in that's case you should always put it there. A strong PC will always run with more frames per second then a phone no matter how simple you think your app is.

In this specific case though you assign a [**`velocity`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

> A velocity in Unity is units **per second**

so it already **is** a frame-rate independent fixed value. The physics engine itself already takes care of moving the correct amount per physics update and you do **not** want to multiply by `Time.deltaTime` in this case.

You want to do

```
void movement()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, speed);
}
```

Comment: I get your point, but as it is already working fine with deltatime and I got two suggestions saying I should use deltatime i used it. But I wanna understand, does using deltatime in my case have any down side?

Comment: @ManSal yes, as said it makes no sense in your case. It just makes it harder for you to calculate/estimate working values since they will be divided by about `60` (depending on your final frame-rate) .. as said in general, yes you want to use `Time.deltaTime` whenever you have to calculate a continous absolute movement value on a per frame basis ... That's not the case for the sample you show and here you definitely do not want to do it => the comments are simply wrong / not applying to your specific use case ;)